# Extract data from a SOAP API using Python

Tags: python, api, soap

we are trying to do a POC in python to extract data and dump it as an excel file from a SOAP API.
We have not got any useful public facing API's. Please provide your inputs regarding this and any sample scripts where if we sent 1 or 2 headers how the response can be parsed as a file.

Comment: You can use **requests** library to get a response and the **pandas** library to create dataframe and save as excel. Please explain the question more clearly.

Comment: Thanks Anshuman, our attempt is to sent parameters to the SOAP API for eg list of employees who joined after november. Input would be 01-Nov-2019 and it would return employe_name,employee_code,employee_DOJ,employee_department. Any similar examples can help us out here.